# bash: output contents of diff function into 2 columns

Tags: bash, sed, diff, matching

I have a file that looks like so:

```
 file1.txt
 rs13339951:45007956:T:C 45007956
 rs2838331 45026728
 rs5647 12335
 rs4687576 5353566

 file2.txt
 rs13339951 45007956
 rs2838331 45026728
 rs5647 12335
 rs4687576:ATCFHF 5353566
```

More descriptions:

- Some of the values in column1 are identical between the 2 files but not all
- The values in column2 are all identical between the 2 files

I want to identify the rows for which the values in column1 differs between the 2 files. I.e. these rows 1 and 4 in my example. I can do this with diff file1.txt and file2.txt.

However, I would like to obtain a end file like so (see below). Indeed, I aim to use sed to replace the names of one file in the other so that both files match completely.

```
rs13339951:45007956:T:C rs13339951
rs4687576 rs4687576:ATCFHF
```

Comment: What have you tried?  You could do this with `awk` or possibly, `join`.

Comment: I was considering doing something like: 

    diff file1.txt file2.txt | grep \^\< | sed's/< //' > part1.txt
    diff file1.txt file2.txt | grep \^\> | sed's/> //' > part2.txt

And the somehow matching the 2 files based on positions to obtain one file like the one above. It just seems quite clumsy and tedious though. I need to do this for over 500 files at the same time so one single command would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk is perfect for this

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$2]=$1; next}  a[$2]!=$1 {print a[$2] " " $1}' file1 file2
```

outputs

```
rs13339951:45007956:T:C rs13339951
rs4687576 rs4687576:ATCFHF
```

---

We are passing two files to awk. It will pass over them consecutively.

```
FNR==NR {.... next} { ... }
```

With this "trick" the first action is executed for the first file and the second action is executed for the second file.

```
a[$2]=$1
```

A key value lookup table. Second column is key first column is value. We build this lookup table while reading the first file.

```
a[$2]!=$1 {print a[$2] " " $1}
```

While iterating over the second file, compare the current first column with the value in the lookup table. If they do not match print the desired output.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be possible for you to explain exactly what each part of this code does? I'm quite new to bash so i'm not sure exactly what each part of your command is doing

Comment: @m93 Updated my answer. Let me know if there are further questions.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's really helpful!